# Codeigniter Controller 404 & routing issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

so I've had experience building codeigniter applications in the past so I'm slightly familiar with the framework

however anytime prior I've worked directly from the root (http://domain.com/)

I'm currently trying to develop & deploy an application which will be hosted in subfolders (http://domain.com/foo/bar)

I have a decent grasp on routing but I'm not sure what's going on. going to http://domain.com/foo/bar loads without issue, but anytime I try to add a new route such as http://domain.com/foo/bar/myController -- I get a 404. The server is essentially trying to load http://domain.com/foo/bar/myController/index.php versus using the framework controller--

is this some kind of server configuration or setting? do I have to do something with htaccess? (all I have had to do in the past is scrub index.php out of the URL)

for the record the issue is not that the controller is broken/missing/named improperly, if I set the default controller to myController the page will load without issue.

I'm a little confused and looking for any kind of advice. thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled with Apache?  If so, do you have an .htaccess file in the root of your application (i.e. next to the CI index.php) that matches https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Mod-rewrite?  Lastly, have you allowed overrides in your httpd.conf file within your CodeIgniter directory?

Comment: hey there-- yeah, I have that exact .htaccess file in the root folder of my CI install. oddly enough I cannot see the mod_rewrite module in phpinfo() output, but I am confident we have used htaccess files to change URLs before with rewrite. I also checked my usual development server (where I have working codeigniter applications) and had the same issue 'locating' the mod_rewrite module-- in regards to the httpd.conf file I'm not entirely confident. I know it's a windows server running apache if that makes a difference, but currently I only have FTP access, not terminal/SSH access.

Comment: If you really have that exact .htaccess file, then you need to change the RewriteBase directive in the .htaccess file.  The RewriteBase in your case should be the URL that will point to your CodeIgniter index.php, I think.  If your CI index.php is accessible from `domain.com/foo/bar/index.php` then your RewriteBase should probably be `/foo/bar/`.  Then again, the RewriteBase directive could also be the CI root directory as it is named on your server's filesystem.  The [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) were not especially explicit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to set `base_url` (application/config/config.php):

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://domain.com/foo/bar';
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated this in my post but I have the base_url properly setup. 

one thing that could POSSIBLY be part of the problem-- the install is located on domain.com/foo/bar but the 'real path' is domain.com/foobar/bar (I'm not sure what's being used to rewrite the folder name but I'd assume htaccess or some other kind of server config)

just for clarification of the above: the 'live' URL shows up and works as: domain.com/foobar/bar but in the FTP the first folder is actually named 'foo'